# Stuck at "Loading operating system..."

Tags: hard-drive, boot, cpu

Today I got out an old PC from about 2011, running a Sandy Bridge i3. It had no ram or HDD in it, so I threw 4GB and a HDD in and attempted to install Ubuntu.
After making sure the BIOS settings were all correct, I attempted to boot from the USB stick, where it takes me to a screen that says "Loading operating system..." with a flashing cursor.

This has the same behaviour with any of the USB ports, any of my bootable USB's, and even another HDD with an OS already on it.
This is with both EFI and non-EFI disks.

Could it be a faulty CPU or something? Really at a loss here.

Comment: If it was a faulty CPU it wouldn't even POST

Comment: Are you the USB drive is OK?

Comment: @TylerDarby : Ok - this is from the olden golden days. :-)  One of the problems older systems used to have was a build-up of oxidation.  All of that power flowing through the chips would cause this to happen.  So one of the things you had to do was to unplug everything, take the whole thing apart, take out the cpu, use a WHITE eraser that doesn't smudge to gently clean the prongs and gold connectors on all cards and chips, put everything back together, plug it all in, and try it again. Not guaranteed to work but it has brought many older systems back from the dead.

Comment: @TylerDarby : BTW - Don't pry chips off of the motherboard.  They either are socketed (like the CPUs usually are) or they are soldered.  Don't muck with the soldered stuff.  If you have cards in your computer, remember to rock them back and forth to remove them.  Don't just yank them out.  And if you blow your system up - not my problem.  If you aren't comfortable doing this - find a hobby group in your area and take your system there so they can show you how to do this.  This is just a FYI.  Ya pays ya money and ya takes ya chances - as the saying goes. :-)